# C++ OpenGL Window Kit

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl, frameworks

Besides Qt, GTK, wxWidgets... What are the recommendations for a **cross platform, open source** GUI framework library that works with OpenGL?

Comment: I found a discussion on the many alternatives:

http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=444230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not quite a GUI framework. But GLFW is good for an OpenGL window with some extra features like keyboard and joystick handling.

I found the other framework I was looking for.  It is SFML.  I only used it briefly but I do remember liking it very much.  It does contain a lot of nice extras going a step further than GLFW.  If I recall correctly the documentation was stellar.

For a full featured cross-platform GUI framework I think you would be hard pressed to beat QT, GTK, or wx.

Comment: I've often wanted to beat GTK. With something large and heavy.

Comment: To update; GLFW is most impressive. Definitely worth the time; thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but at a guess, the other framework mfperzel was trying to think of might have been [fltk](http://www.fltk.org/) (the "fast light tool kit"). Where glfw is mostly an OpenGL window with *some* ability to read the mouse and keyboard, fltk is a GUI framework that supports OpenGL (but as the name implies it's still quite a bit smaller and faster than most GUI frameworks). I haven't tried it yet, but there's a new GUI builder program for it ([FLUID](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.1/fluid.html)) that looks fairly promising as well. One warning though: FLTK uses its own widgets, which tend to look at least a little foreign to most users.